# Как запретить показ выпадающих списков в ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

Мне нужно запретить в `ExpandableListView` показ выпадающих списков в определенный момент времени, я пробую  `expListView.setEnabled(false)`, выпадающие списки не показываются, но перестает работать скроллинг элементов в ExpandableListView. Какие еще есть варианты, что бы скроллинг не переставал работать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй так:

```
expandableList.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                              int groupPosition, long id) { 
    return true; // This way the expander cannot be collapsed
  }
});
```

Comment: Кирилл, спасибо, работает!